# base path issues file not found internal server error! (Status 500)

Tags: php

I'm migrating my project from xampp to a server and my autoloader can't pick up any of my classes and I believe it's due to my base path being incorrect I'm receiving this error: any ideas?

internal server error! (Status 500)
Message: File not found: errorController
File: /home/user/public_html/assignment/part_1/includes/autoloader.inc.php
Line: 60

Config.inc.php

```
define('BASEPATH', '/assignment/part_1/');
```

Request.php

```
class request {

    private $basepath =  BASEPATH;
    private $path;
    private $requestMethod;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])['path'];
        $this->path = strtolower(str_replace($this->basepath, "", $this->path));
        $this->path = trim($this->path,"/");
        $this->requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    }
```

URL:
http://server/assignment/part_1/

Autoloader

```
function myAutoLoader($className){
    /** src path */
    $src = "src\\" . strtolower($className) . ".php";
    $src = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $src);

    /** controllers path */
    $pathControllers = "src//controllers//" . strtolower($className) . ".php";
    $pathControllers = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathControllers);

    /** gateway path */
    $pathGateway = "src//gateways//" . strtolower($className) . ".php";
    $pathGateway = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathGateway);

    /** pages path */
    $pathPages = "src//pages//" . strtolower($className) . ".php";
    $pathPages = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathPages);

     /** response and request path */
     $pathResponse = "src//responses//" . strtolower($className) . ".php";
     $pathResponse = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathResponse);

     /** response and request path */
     $pathJWT = "src//firebase//jwt" . strtolower($className) . ".php";
     $pathJWT = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathResponse);
```

Comment: We can't see your server config or where you've copied your files to.

Comment: I'm copying files to /home/user/public_html/assignment/part_1/ @ADyson
and the server is http://server/assignment/part_1/

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70667922/edit) with any and all extra info which is relevant. Thanks.